# Converting subqueries to JOIN statements for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my current query:

```
 SELECT prod.id,
       prod.title,
       prod.price,
       prod.status,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   payments
        WHERE  product = prod.id
               AND ( vendor = '1'
                     AND credited = 'Vendor' )
               AND ( status = 'Completed'
                      OR status = 'Pending'
                      OR status = 'Canceled_Reversal' )) AS sales,
       (SELECT SUM(price)
        FROM   payments
        WHERE  product = prod.id
               AND ( vendor = '1'
                     AND credited = 'Vendor' )
               AND ( status = 'Completed'
                      OR status = 'Pending'
                      OR status = 'Canceled_Reversal' )) AS revenue
FROM   products prod
WHERE  member = '1'
       AND status != 'Deleted' 
       AND status != 'Blocked'
```

Right now I'm using 2 subqueries inside the main query.

Is there any way to use JOIN statements instead or simplify the query to speed it up?

Or is nothing going to make it much faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write this a bit simpler:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.price, p.status,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM payments pa
        WHERE pa.product = p.id AND
              pa.vendor = p.member AND
              pa.credited = 'Vendor' AND
              pa.status IN ('Completed','Pending', 'Canceled_Reversal')
      ) AS sales,
       (SELECT SUM(pa.price)
        FROM payments pa
        WHERE pa.product = p.id AND
              pa.vendor = p.member AND
              pa.credited = 'Vendor' AND
              pa.status IN ('Completed','Pending','Canceled_Reversal')
      ) AS revenue
FROM products p
WHERE p.member = 1 AND
      p.status NOT IN ('Deleted', 'Blocked');
```

This is basically your query with simpler aliases and logic.

With an index on `payments(product, vendor, credit, status, price)`, this is probably faster than other methods.

An alternative is:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.price, p.status,
       COUNT(pa.product) as sales
       SUM(pa.price) as revenue
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     payments pa
     ON pa.product = p.id AND
        pa.vendor = p.member AND
        pa.credited = 'Vendor' AND
        pa.status IN ('Completed', 'Pending', 'Canceled_Reversal')
WHERE p.member = 1 AND
      p.status NOT IN ('Deleted', 'Blocked')
GROUP BY p.id, p.title, p.price, p.status;
```

However, the subqueries are probably faster.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfect!  Are subqueries normally faster that joins?

Comment: @ShadowAccount . . . Sometimes, there is no hard rule.  The real comparison is to aggregation and avoiding the outer aggregation generally benefits performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a join with aggregation:

```
SELECT
    prod.id,
    prod.title,
    prod.price,
    prod.status,
    COALESCE(t.sales, 0) AS sales,
    COALESCE(t.revenue, 0) AS revenue
FROM products prod
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        product,
        COUNT(*) AS sales,
        SUM(price) AS revenue
    FROM payments p
    WHERE vendor = '1' AND credited = 'Vendor' AND
          status IN ('Completed', 'Pending', 'Canceled_Reversal')
    GROUP BY product
) t
    ON t.product = prod.id;
```

Note that we use a *left* join here, to cater for the possibility that some product in the `products` table might not even have any matching data in the `payments` table.  In that case, we also use `COALESCE` to report zero values for the sales and revenue.

The subquery aliased as `t` above could probably be optimzed using the following index:

```
payments (product, vendor, credit, status, price)
```